# Возможно ли соединяться с своим сервером NextCloud по локальной сети?

Tags: linux, сеть, nextcloud

Хочу настроить NextCloud. Собрал себе сервер, купил статический IP. Но хотел бы узнать, возможно ли установить две сетевые карты и одна будет соединена с роутером в интернет, а вторая с другим роутером в локальную сеть. Так как у меня интернет всего 100 мбит/с. А по локалке можно 1000 выжать. На случай если уеду из дома - значит буду через интернет иметь доступ к NextCloud, а как приеду домой, то могу и через локальную сеть. Если кто с таким сталкивался, посоветуйте пожайлуста, нужно ли ставить вторую сетевую карту или нет?

Comment: две сетевые не нужны. Просто в локальной сети обращайтесь по "внутреннему айпи" и всех делов то.

Comment: и два роутера, наверняка, тоже...